# tExtractJsonFields getting data from 3 levels

Tags: json, talend

I am trying to extract 3 levels of data from JSON with tExtractFields.
I know tHMap can do this but I am having trouble with that approach so I am pursuing a simpler approach for now.

I am working with a Smartsheet JSON response describing a sheet within Smartsheet.
There are 3 levels

- Lvl 1 - Sheet info[]

  - Lvl 2 - Column Info[]
  - Lvl 2 - Row info[]

    - Lvl 3 - cell info[]

Using tExtractJsonFields, I am able to retrieve information from Level 1 and Level 3.
I do not know the correct JsonQuery to correctly retrieve level 2.

**My problem**
 I would like to extract information from Level 2 Row.Id, Row.Value in the same tExtractJsonFields component.  
Any help would be appreciated.

**tExtractJsonFields configuration**
[image: tExtractJsonFields]

**tLogRow Output**

Fields 2 and 3 are null.
Clearly, I am doing something wrong.
[image: tLogRow Output]

**Sample JSON**

```
    {    "id": 8566480355780484,
        "columns": [
            {    "id": 7605383392978820,
                "title": "Item #"
            },
            {    "id": 1975883858765700,
                "title": "Indicator"
            }
        ],
        "rows": [
            {    "id": 4808422210070404,
                "rowNumber": 1,
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "columnId": 7605383392978820,
                        "value": "0002",
                        "displayValue": "0002"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnId": 1975883858765700,
                        "value": "Draft",
                        "displayValue": "Draft"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {    "id": 2556622396385156,
                "rowNumber": 2,
                "cells": [
                    {    "columnId": 7605383392978820,
                        "value": "0003",
                        "displayValue": "0003"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is another way, but I did find a way using an approach Talend outlines in their documentation [here](https://help.talend.com/r/x4dRAoT8i4Q7d98atKeNYw/gLYy0GSsTjrcYnuBPfa_Eg).

The trick is to parse the higher levels in prior tExtractJsonFields components and then let that information flow through by simply leaving those JSON queries blank in the subsequent components.

The tFilterRow component is simply to exclude items that have only null values.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]